# Python Networkx - Color nodes according to different centrality measures

Tags: python, networkx

I am wanting to draw a network where each node is colored according to the centrality of that node.

I'm very new to python and so far I have my network and the dictionary of centrality values for each node. Eg: large degree centralizes will be colored dark and the low degree dentralities will be light colored according to some continuous color spectrum.

So far I have,

```
sw0 = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(300,3,0.05)
dcent = nx.degree_centrality(sw1)
ecent = nx.degree_centrality(sw1)
bcent = nx.betweenness_centrality(sw1)
ccent = nx.closeness_centrality(sw1)

plt.figure(1)
nx.draw(sw0,pos=None,with_labels=False,node_size=5,width=0.05)
plt.savefig("sw0.png",dpi=500)
```

Any help is appreciate including links to further research. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a list of color values to the nx.draw method.
The simplest form would be to convert the dcent dict values into a list:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sw0 = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(300,3,0.05)
dcent = nx.degree_centrality(sw0)
dcent_color = [dcent[i] for i in range(len(dcent))]
ecent = nx.degree_centrality(sw0)
bcent = nx.betweenness_centrality(sw0)
ccent = nx.closeness_centrality(sw0)

plt.figure(1)
nx.draw(sw0,pos=None,with_labels=False,node_size=5,node_color=dcent_color,width=0.05)
plt.savefig("sw0.png",dpi=500)
```

[Resulting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3F2t.png)